# Predicate: traditional vs. modern view / semantics vs. syntax

Tags: semantics, traditional-grammar

According to traditional grammar, the predicate is the part of a sentence that modifies the subject, i.e., the sentence can be divided into two parts: the subject and the predicate. For example, in the sentence *The kids may have started the game*, the NP (*the kids*) is the subject and the VP (*may have started the game*) is the predicate. I know that the term *predicate* identifies elements in the language system and *predicator* identifies the semantic roles. The former is related to syntax/grammar while the latter is related to semantics (argument structure). However, inspired by predicate calculus, modern theories of syntax and grammar see predicates as relations between or functions over arguments. Predicates assign a property to a single argument or relate two or more arguments to one other, e.g., *Sam helped you* (*help* is a predicate, while *Sam* and *you* are arguments). Up to this point it's clear.

Now, Hurford (2007) defines *predicator* and *predicate* as follows:

**Predicator**

> The predicator of a simple declarative sentence is the word (sometimes
>   a (partial) group of words) which does not belong to any of the
>   referring expressions and which, of the remainder, makes the most
>   specific contribution to the meaning of the sentence. Intuitively
>   speaking, the predicator describes the state or process in which the
>   referring expressions are involved.

**Predicate**

> Predicate is any word (or sequence of words) which (in a given single
>   sense) can function as the predicator of a sentence.

The problem arises with the following example:

> *A tall, handsome stranger entered the saloon.*

This sentence only contains one predicator (*enter*) but the sentence also contains the words *tall*, *handsome*, *stranger* and *saloon*, all of which are predicates, and can function as predicators in other sentences, e.g. *John is tall*, *He is handsome*, *He is a stranger* and *That ramshackle building is a saloon.*

Now, some people illustrate this specific example as:

> *A tall, handsome stranger* (predicate) and *entered* (predicator)

While others, on the basis of traditional grammar, argue that since *A handsome stranger* is the subject of the sentence, it cannot be a predicate. According to them:

> *A tall, handsome stranger* (subject), *entered the saloon* (predicate) and *entered* (predicator)

In my view, the sentence can be illustrated as follows:

> *A tall, handsome stranger* (argument of predicate) *entered* (matrix
>   predicate/predicator) *the saloon* (argument of predicate)

*A tall, handsome stranger* (as a subject) may not necessarily be acting as a predicate in this specific sentence, but the illustration given in Hurford (2007) may simply mean that these words can act as predicator or predicate in other sentences e.g. *He is tall*, *He is handsome* and *He is a stranger*. In all these sentences, the VP (*is tall*, *is handsome*, *is a stranger*) is a predicate and the words *tall*, *handsome* and *stranger* are predicators. Is this correct?

The question is about the first group who label the sentence according to traditional grammar and are confused when they interpret *A tall handsome stranger* as the predicate in the sentence *A tall, handsome stranger entered the saloon.*

Comment: Please [edit] this to fix all your typos and to mark out quotes with the > symbol. It is too hard to understand clearly as it is now.

Comment: Please [edit] this to format the quotes with the > symbol. It is essential that you do that because otherwise we cannot tell what is your words and what you are quoting.

Comment: The question is good, since it is pointing to an area where there is much variation among grammarians. Exactly what a predicate is supposed to be varies a lot based on the grammar tradition one is coming from. Some grammarians acknowledge predicators, others do not. There is much confusion in the area in general.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read Hurford (2007), but it sounds confused.  Whether an expression of natural language refers and whether it predicates are not exclusive properties.  In the usual rendering of natural language sentences into predicate logic, a noun phrase translates into an argument, which may have a referent, and predications on that argument.  Trying to parse language expressions into referring expressions and non-referring expressions doesn't give you anything like a traditional division into subject and predicate, or between noun and verb.

You might be interested in Charles Fillmore's idea about the "subject choice hierarchy" -- a part of his Case Grammar.  Natural language sentences are given representations in which a verb is supplied with a number of arguments, as a logic predicate has a number of arguments, but with each argument is associated a case, and there are general rules for choosing which argument-with-case will be made the superficial subject.

Predicates don't modify subjects -- they predicate.

Comment: how would you analyze this sentence 'A tall, handsome stranger entered the saloon'

Comment: is it correct to say that  'A tall, handsome stranger' is predicate in this sentence and word entered s predicator? - Greg Lee

Comment: @shasha  In the usual rendering into predicate logic, in "a tall handsome stranger", the "a" corresponds to an existential quantifier, and "tall", "handsome", "stranger" correspond to predicates: (Ex)( x is tall & x is handsome & x is a stranger & x entered the room ).

Comment: @shasha I looked up the Wikipedia account of predicate(grammar), and, as I thought, it does *not* say that a predicate modifies a subject.  You are wrong about this.

Comment: @shasha, you're right that the Wikipedia article does attribute to dictionaries the idea that a predicate modifies a subject.  However, I don't think that's right.  Predication is not the same as modification.

Comment: I agree modification is not suitable word, the author would have used it perhaps to give a rough idea to the reader.

Comment: I do understand that when we say ( x is tall & x is handsome & x is a stranger & x entered the room ) "tall", "handsome", "stranger" correspond to predicates. it's only when we look at these words individually with a verb. what about the case when they occur at the sentence initial position as a subject. like in A tall, handsome stranger entered the saloon'. here Tall handsome stranger is acting as a subject and according to traditional grammar the subject part is not the Predicate of sentence but the one with the verb like entered the salon is the predicate part.

Comment: @shasha, for one thing, notice that adjectives can't modify definite pronouns, but it is perfectly okay to predicate adjectives of definite pronoun subjects. "It is green." / *"Green it is attractive."